# Batch File Character Encoding on Windows Seven?

Tags: file, batch-file, windows-7, utf-8, character-encoding

How do I know what character encoding to save a batch file as?

I've heard that windows uses difrent charset for cmd and GUIs.

Comment: If you save it, retrieve it, run it and it works, does it really matter what charset it is?  GUIs are graphical interfaces: they can use any charset/font encoding.  Did you really mean GUI or GUI source code?  Why do you need to know this?

Answer (score 1):

It depends on the character set implemented by cmd.

```
C:\Users\>chcp
Active code page: 437
```

[Code page 437](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Code_page_437) is (I believe) the default for Windows systems. It uses ASCII encoding, and the following character set:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You can use chcp to display and config the active code page.

Show chcp usage:

```
C:\> chcp /?
```

Show current code page:

```
C:\> chcp
```

Config active code page (example):

```
C:\> chcp 437
```

Answer (score 0):

I think the question has to do with localization, e.g., for echo messages in a .bat file.  (and not line-endings or anything like that)

The question for me is then how can a .bat file control being treated as UTF-8 and not the local default code page.  Is there a cue to cmd.exe that will get that to work?

In scripts built and used in an international setting, this matters.